# Allow user registration via API and from website rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Currently I am working on sample web application. In this application, user can sign up via JSON API as well as from browser.

For JSON API authentication I have used **gem devise_token_auth** https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth and it is working fine. I am able to sign up via API.

But now I have to provide sign up functionality from the web browser.
(URL: http://localhost:3000/auth/sign_up) getting following error

```
The action 'new' could not be found for DeviseTokenAuth::RegistrationsController
```

So how can I allow sign up from the web browser.

Here is my routes.rb file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'
end
```

Generated routes

```
                  Prefix Verb     URI Pattern                            Controller#Action
        new_user_session GET      /auth/sign_in(.:format)                devise_token_auth/sessions#new
            user_session POST     /auth/sign_in(.:format)                devise_token_auth/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE   /auth/sign_out(.:format)               devise_token_auth/sessions#destroy
       new_user_password GET      /auth/password/new(.:format)           devise_token_auth/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET      /auth/password/edit(.:format)          devise_token_auth/passwords#edit
           user_password PATCH    /auth/password(.:format)               devise_token_auth/passwords#update
                         PUT      /auth/password(.:format)               devise_token_auth/passwords#update
                         POST     /auth/password(.:format)               devise_token_auth/passwords#create
cancel_user_registration GET      /auth/cancel(.:format)                 devise_token_auth/registrations#cancel
   new_user_registration GET      /auth/sign_up(.:format)                devise_token_auth/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET      /auth/edit(.:format)                   devise_token_auth/registrations#edit
       user_registration PATCH    /auth(.:format)                        devise_token_auth/registrations#update
                         PUT      /auth(.:format)                        devise_token_auth/registrations#update
                         DELETE   /auth(.:format)                        devise_token_auth/registrations#destroy
                         POST     /auth(.:format)                        devise_token_auth/registrations#create
     auth_validate_token GET      /auth/validate_token(.:format)         devise_token_auth/token_validations#validate_token
            auth_failure GET      /auth/failure(.:format)                devise_token_auth/omniauth_callbacks#omniauth_failure
                         GET      /auth/:provider/callback(.:format)     devise_token_auth/omniauth_callbacks#omniauth_success
                         GET|POST /omniauth/:provider/callback(.:format) devise_token_auth/omniauth_callbacks#redirect_callbacks
        omniauth_failure GET|POST /omniauth/failure(.:format)            devise_token_auth/omniauth_callbacks#omniauth_failure
                         GET      /auth/:provider(.:format)              redirect(301)
```

Do I have to add separate devise here. Please let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to achieve this will be to mount normal devise routes to one scope, and API devise_token_auth routes to separate scope.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  # standard devise routes at /users
  devise_for :users

  # token auth routes available at /api/auth/
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    scope module: :v1 do
      mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_user_registration GET      /auth/sign_up(.:format)                devise_token_auth/registrations#new
```

which does not lead to anything, because in the `GEM` controller [`devise_token_auth/registrations_controller`](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/master/app/controllers/devise_token_auth/registrations_controller.rb) there is no new action.

1 - **change the routing** so that the `http GET` request is rooted to your `controller#new` action.

2 - create the **controller#new** action

3 - have the form in `new.html.erb` call the following action

```
POST     /auth(.:format)                        devise_token_auth/registrations#create
```

4 - To create a user, you just need to make an `HTTP POST` request to the following URL

```
POST     /auth(.:format)                        devise_token_auth/registrations#create
```

with the parameters that you need to pass to this controller action

```
def create
  @resource            = resource_class.new(sign_up_params)
  @resource.provider   = "email"

  # honor devise configuration for case_insensitive_keys
  if resource_class.case_insensitive_keys.include?(:email)
    @resource.email = sign_up_params[:email].try :downcase
  else
    @resource.email = sign_up_params[:email]
  end

  # give redirect value from params priority
  @redirect_url = params[:confirm_success_url]

  # fall back to default value if provided
  @redirect_url ||= DeviseTokenAuth.default_confirm_success_url

  # success redirect url is required
  if resource_class.devise_modules.include?(:confirmable) && !@redirect_url
    return render_create_error_missing_confirm_success_url
  end

  # if whitelist is set, validate redirect_url against whitelist
  if DeviseTokenAuth.redirect_whitelist
    unless DeviseTokenAuth::Url.whitelisted?(@redirect_url)
      return render_create_error_redirect_url_not_allowed
    end
  end

  begin
    # override email confirmation, must be sent manually from ctrl
    resource_class.set_callback("create", :after, :send_on_create_confirmation_instructions)
    resource_class.skip_callback("create", :after, :send_on_create_confirmation_instructions)
    if @resource.save
      yield @resource if block_given?

      unless @resource.confirmed?
        # user will require email authentication
        @resource.send_confirmation_instructions({
          client_config: params[:config_name],
          redirect_url: @redirect_url
        })

      else
        # email auth has been bypassed, authenticate user
        @client_id = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(nil, false)
        @token     = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(nil, false)

        @resource.tokens[@client_id] = {
          token: BCrypt::Password.create(@token),
          expiry: (Time.now + DeviseTokenAuth.token_lifespan).to_i
        }

        @resource.save!

        update_auth_header
      end
      render_create_success
    else
      clean_up_passwords @resource
      render_create_error
    end
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
    clean_up_passwords @resource
    render_create_error_email_already_exists
  end
end
```

This way the user will be created, but it is not a good approach. You are using an `api` when you should just be using `devise`